# URL param dissappear after onClick event

Tags: apex, visualforce, event, commandbutton

I tried researching on this particular topic and found a similar problem here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096Q1IAI

Unsure what causes the param to dissapear after I click on the onClick button and the page is refresh instead of redirecting(the action is not triggered)

Basically the method will prompt user using the JSmethod . If yes, proceed to the black page when the col variable is Black.

Any idea guys?

Controller:

```
public PageReference Process(){
    if (col == 'black'){
           dip c = new dip(col);   
           pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/blackpage');
           pageRef.setRedirect(true);
     } else {
           pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/whitepage');
           pageRef.setRedirect(true);

     }
   return pageRef;
}


VF code:
function JSmethod() {



    if('{!col}' == 'Black'){ 
        var isCancel = confirm("Black?");    
        if (isCancel) window.location.href = "/blackpage"; 
        return false;

         }  
    } 
    <apex:commandButton action="{!process}" value="Black" onClick="return JSmethod();" />
```

Comment: What is @dip c = new dip(col);  ?

Comment: @Prabhat that's my internal class.